# How to count number of orders prior to current order

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have orders table:

```
| order_id | buyer_id | order_created_at    |
|----------|----------|---------------------|
| 54       | 609      | 2018-08-11 16:46:53 |
| 74       | 363      | 2019-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 75       | 300      | 2019-06-01 00:00:02 |
| 76       | 609      | 2019-06-01 00:00:03 |
```

I want to show the data like this:

```
| order_id | buyer_id | Number_of_orders_plus_this_order |
|----------|----------|----------------------------------|
| 54       | 609      |                                2 |
| 74       | 363      |                                4 |
| 75       | 300      |                                7 |
| 76       | 609      |                                5 |
```

I tried two ways, the first one:

```
select t1.order_id, orders.buyer_id, count(1) as Number_of_orders_plus_this_order
from (
 select buyer_id, order_created_at, order_id
 from orders o1
 where o1.order_id in (75, 74, 54,76)
) as t1
join orders on orders.buyer_id = t1.buyer_id
where orders.order_created_at <= t1.order_created_at
group by 1, 2
```

Since there is one of the buyers (with id: 609) showed two times, and I grouped by buyer_id this will show results that ignores one of his orders.
like this:

```
| order_id | buyer_id | Number_of_orders_plus_this_order |
|----------|----------|----------------------------------|
| 54       | 609      |                                2 |
| 74       | 363      |                                4 |
| 75       | 300      |                                7 |
```

The second way is using python, I made a loop for each order and query the database. this of course takes a very long time and it's not practical at all.

Comment: What does "Number_of_orders_plus_this_order" mean?  How does the first table relate to the second?

Comment: I can't figure out how the data set corresponds to the result set. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: expected result does not seams to be possible with the example data, unless i mis something very very very obvious it seams/sounds like you are looking for a some kind of `running total + 1`?

Comment: my idea to include the current order in the count, so the order doesn't get ignored if it was the first order.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: Yep, the sample data is incomplete, thus obfuscating the request. I looked at the query in order to understand what's been meant :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT order_id, buyer_id, order_created_at, 1 + (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM orders AS x
    WHERE x.buyer_id = t.buyer_id
    AND (
        x.order_created_at < o.order_created_at OR (
            -- orders having same date need a tie breaker
            x.order_created_at = o.order_created_at
            AND x.order_id < o.order_id
        )
    )
) AS number_of_orders_plus_this_order
FROM orders AS t
WHERE order_id IN (75, 74, 54, 76)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? After posting my answer, I notice that my answer equals this and I see nothing wrong about our answers. Salman A even points out possible ties and how to deal with them. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show particular orders. For each of these you want to count the orders placed by the same buyer until then.

You can do this easily with a subquery in the select clause:

```
select
  o.*,
  (
    select count(*)
    from orders o2
    where o2.buyer_id = o.buyer_id
      and o2.order_created_at <= o.order_created_at
  ) as num_of orders
from orders o
where order_id in (75, 74, 54, 76)
order by order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to enumerate the orders and then extract the enumeration for a handful of orders?  If so, use window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, row_number() over (order by order_created_at) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where o.order_id in (75, 74, 54, 76);
```

Comment: They want a partition by buyer_id it seems. Apart from that, this should work. And it's a nice way of writing the query. I don't understand the downvote. +1 from me.